# Django templates, pass template language through a template variable

Tags: django, django-templates

I was thinking about putting my static pages in the database (simple model of url, title and content) and then having a basic base_static.html template - making them super easy to edit (from admin interface) if necessary.

I know you can easily escape html like so:

```
{{ content|safe }}
```

or

```
{% autoescape off %}
{{ content }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

But I need to be able to use some of the template language in the static pages, e.g. a simple for loop to go over variables passed to it from the view.

Is this possible, or would you recommend simply using templates to serve the static pages?(They won't change that much ever)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you're iterating over a variable to populate a region of a page, it's not really static at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store templates in db (and that is what you want if you want to use a template language) you can use this app : [django-dbtemplates](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-dbtemplates).

Answer (score 0):

Check this question: [Extending Django Flatpages to accept template tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066270/extending-django-flatpages-to-accept-template-tags)

You may get some ideas from the solution exposed there