# Can't use {{MEDIA_URL}} in Django Flatpages?

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, django-flatpages

A rather simple question which I will elaborate on if needed in order to solve the problem.

I attempted to use a simple call to `{{ MEDIA_URL }}` in order to show an image on an About Us Django flatpage, but it seems the flatpage is ignoring the fact that it is a Django variable and simply taking `{{MEDIA_URL}}` as text?

I supplied: `<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}images/static/Deb-and-Diana-About-Us.jpg" alt="Deb &amp; Diana Portrait" width="300" height="384" align="left">` but when the template is rendered it doesn't append the MEDIA_URL where it should, it just leaves the words `{{ MEDIA_URL }}`.

Am I missing an import or something?  The default.html which governs the flatpage extends my usual template so I see no reason why this should fail, unless I don't understand what flatpages have access to?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extending Django Flatpages to accept template tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066270/extending-django-flatpages-to-accept-template-tags)

Comment: @AamirAdnan This question has nothing to do with what you have marked as duplicate..

Comment: @karthikr how? What is difference between a MEDIA_URL and other template tags or context?

Comment: @AamirAdnan The question is, How to I enable `MEDIA_URL` in flatpages, not how do i make flatpages accept templatetags. There are many ways of doing that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access the `MEDIA_URL` in flat pages via a templatetag. [Look at this snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/654/)
It searches for `{{ MEDIA_URL }}` and replaces it with that found in your settings.

```
from django import template
from django.conf import settings
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
@stringfilter
def media_url(value):
    """Searches for {{ MEDIA_URL }} and replaces it with the MEDIA_URL from settings.py"""
    return value.replace('{{ MEDIA_URL }}', settings.MEDIA_URL)
media_url.is_safe = True
```

And the usage:

```
{% load media_url %}
{{ flatpage.content|media_url }}
```

To set up, drop the above code into a file called `media_url.py` in your `templatetags` directory in one of your `INSTALLED_APPS`, and add the filter to your flatpages template like so

Comment: This is a perfect, simple solution to a problem that called for one.  Thanks a bunch karthikr!