# Evaluate string as template tag - Django

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a Django template which includes a template tag that takes a variable (shop.id) and returns one of two string depending on whether the shop is in a database model, like this

```
{% is_shop_claimed shop.id %}
```

The two possible strings returned by the template tag are

```
return '<p>Taken</p>'
```

or

```
return '<a href="/claim_shop/{{shop.id}}/">Claim shop now</a>'
```

When the code is run, if the second string is returned, it appears in the template (viewing the page source in the browser) like

```
<a href="/claim_shop/{{shop.id}}/">Claim shop now</a>
```

and appears in the browser as a link like this

Claim shop now

**The problem is** that shop.id in the href  **is not evaluated** to a number by the Django template engine.

The link should appear like this for shop 123, for example

```
<a href="/claim_shop/123/">Claim shop now</a>
```

I've checked the Django docs for filters to apply to the string in the template tag or in the template so that the string is not escaped but no luck.

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278042/in-django-is-there-an-easy-way-to-render-a-text-field-as-a-template-in-a-templ) but it seems there should be a simple way making the {{shop.id}} evaluated in the template.

I have also made the template tag to return a Bool instead of the two strings, leaving the presentation in the template like I would prefer, but using an if statement around a template tag like this

```
{% if is_shop_claimed shop.id %}
    <p>Taken</p>
{% elif not is_shop_claimed shop.id %}
    <a href="/claim_shop/{{shop.id}}/">Claim shop now</a>
{% endif %}
```

doesn't work because I can't put the template tag inside the if statement.

Any suggestions on how to get {{shop.id}} to be evaluated to a number? Any help would be appreciated.
I'm learning Django and Python and I have spend hours on this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're being passed the value, so just substitute it in.

```
return '<a href="/claim_shop/%s/">Claim shop now</a>' % (shop_id,) # or however you refer to it in the code
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you add an `is_claimed` property to you shop model:

```
class Shop(models.model):

    # you fields are here

    @property
    def is_claimed(self):
        # logik for determining if the shop is claimed
        if claimed:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Then you can use is in you template:

```
{% if shop.is_claimed %}
    <p>Taken</p>
{% else %}
    <a href="/claim_shop/{{shop.id}}/">Claim shop now</a>
{% endif %}
```

You could even move this to a snippet which you can include as need or (to go even further) create an [inclusion tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) for it.

Comment: I haven't tried this solution because @Ignacio's is much simpler, but thanks again for the answer, and maybe this solution will be handy for someone else.